# Get selected item in a dropdown list in view to CRUD model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

This is done by adding a view from my controller and selecting my dto as template

**My DTO**

```
public class Company_DTO
{
    public long ID_Company { get; set; }
    public string ESTATE_Company { get; set; }
}
```

**MyController**

```
public ActionResult UpdateCompany()
{


     ViewBag.ListOfCompanies = DependencyFactory.Resolve<ICompanyBusiness>().GetCompany(); // this return a List<int> and following what I read for viewbag this should be right.
        return View();
    }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UpdateCompany([Bind]Company_DTO company_DTO)
        {
            try
            {
                //code    
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

**View**

```
    <div class="form-group">            
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID_Company , ViewBag.ListOfCompanies) // Here I get an error on my @Html that my dto does nothave a list.
    </div>
```

I want the selected item to be ID_Company, but here it seems to be trying to add the whole list when I just want the selected item, I cant find any documentation or question that can solve my issue.

I Cant EDIT the DTO.

Thanks for any help and hope I am being clear enough.

Comment: Is model.ID_Company populated? If so, then the ListofCompanies should be the full list of companies and the DropDownListFor will automatically select it. You may have to cast the ViewBag to a List or use linq to convert it to a IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Comment: @RichardHubley How would I do that? I am getting familiar with htmlcs but I dont get how the casting would do, Cast(viewbag.listofcomanies as List<long>)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

**View**

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID_Company, new SelectList(ViewBag.Accounts, "ID_Company", "ESTATE_Company"))
</div>
```

Supposing your view is strongly typed (`@model Company_DTO`).

Hope this helps

Comment: It works, thanks.
Can you explain why do you add the ,"ID_Company"? i erased the rest, given that my list only only has longs
List<long>list

Comment: "ID_Company" is to set the SelectedValue on the HTML tag

Answer (score 1):

consider the following example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Zero", Value = "0"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "One", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Two", Value = "2"}
    };

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Items = items;
        return View(new Boo() { Id = 1, Name = "Boo name"});
    }


}

public class Boo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

the view:
@model WebApi.Controllers.Boo    
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.Items)
```

so, ViewBag.ListOfCompanies should contain IEnumerable. Each SelectListItem has Text and Value property , you need to assign ESTATE_Company  and ID_Company respectively. something like this:

```
var companiesList = //get companies list 
ViewBag.ListOfCompanies = companiesList.Select(x => new SelectListItem() {Text = x.ESTATE_Company, Value = x.ID_Company.ToString()});
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.ID_Company, ViewBag.Items as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand, how do I "parse" my List<long>ID to    ` private List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>()`
@Z.R.T.